# Group and join strings together if in another list entry strings take the same value

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with quarterly firm observations and respective speeches within each firm observation from different persons. As such, I have "common" variables like year, title, firm name etc. and then per quarterly observation I have a variable allinfolistmain which is a stored as a list of lists within each observation containing the name and the speech as separate list entries.

For instance, for one row of "allinfolistmain" the entry would look like this:

```
[[Mark Johnson, Hello], [Christina Brown, Have a good day], [Mark Johnson, You too], [Christina Brown, Thank you]]
```

The overall dataframe would look like this:

```
Index   Year    Title   Firm    allinfolistmain
0   2009    CC A 2009   A   [[Mark Johnson, Hello], [Christina Brown, Have a good day], [Mark Johnson, You too], [Christina Brown, Thank you]]
1   2009    CC B 2009   B   [[Lucas Bass, Hello], [Harm Brown, Have a good day], [Lucas Bass, You too], [Harm Brown, Thank you]]
2   2008    CC A 2008   A   [[Mark Johnson, Nice to see you], [Christina Brown, You too], [Mark Johnson,Thanks], [Christina Brown, Bye]]
```

Now for each row/observation, I want to group the speeches (so list element indexed 1) by name (so list elements indexed 0), so that it looks like below that the speeches are just joined together in one string within the list:

```
[[Mark Johnson, Hello You too], [Christina Brown, Have a good day Thank you]]
```

Could someone help me with the code here how I can go trough each line and create such a new list? All suggestions are very much appreciated as I am still at the beginning of coding and I could not solve this issue.

Thank you so much!
Julia

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to better understand the information you presented and your goal. Are you saying you want to create a dataframe that resembles the second block that has 3 rows? Or do you already have the dataframe, and you want group each "name" in `allinfolistmain` with all their associated speeches? I'll add an answer to further show what I mean.

Comment: Ok, cool no problem. Well there are a couple of answers that might work. Feel free to comment back if you need more help. thanks!

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply! Actually, I had to adapt one thing - I had a list of lists and not a list of tuples. Also, I want it a bit differently than your output below because i have a dataframe already. For example for row 1, I would like: [[Mark Johnson, Hello You too], [Christina Brown, Have a good day Thank you]], for row 2: [[Lucas Bass, Hello You Too], [Harm Brown, Have a good day Thank you]]. So I do not want to add speeches across rows for same speakers, but within rows (observations) for same speakers. Also, I would like it in a list of lists. Or is list of tuples is better?

Comment: Thanks for further explanation. I think I didn't reproduce the dataframe same as you did. Perhaps the other answer works with the dataframe that you already have?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question and how you've created the dataframe, is this what you want to do? At the end is a printed `list`:

```
# a new dictionary of lists to collect all "speeches" values for each "name" key
nd = {}

for row in df['allinfolistmain']:     # for each row in the dataframe 
    for n in row:                     # for each name in the row
        try:                          # 
            if nd[n[0]]:              # check if the key already exists
                nd[n[0]].append(n[1]) # if it does, add speech to its list
        except KeyError:              # otherwise they key doesn't yet exist
            nd[n[0]] = [n[1]]         # we add the key and the speech

newlist = []                          # create a new list

for k, v in nd.iteritems():           # for each key, value in the new dictionary from previous step
    newlist.append((k, ' '.join(v)))  # add a tuple of (key, all speeches) as one string

print newlist
```

output:

```
[('Christina Brown', 'Have a good day Thank you You too Bye'), 
 ('Mark Johnson', 'Hello You too Nice to see you Thanks'), 
 ('Lucas Bass', 'Hello You too'), 
 ('Harm Brown', 'Have a good day Thank you')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
def g(L):
    res = defaultdict(list)
    for v, k in L:
        res[v].append(k)
    new = list({key: ' '.join(value) for key, value in res.items()}.items())
    return new




df.allinfolismain.apply(g)
```

single list test :

```
L=[('Mark Johnson', 'Hello'), ('Christina Brown', 'Have a good day'), ('Mark Johnson', 'You too'), ('Christina Brown', 'Thank you')]
g(L)
Out[784]: 
[('Mark Johnson', 'Hello You too'),
 ('Christina Brown', 'Have a good day Thank you')]
```